# use constraints dynamically sent by api's body

Tags: java, spring-boot, optaplanner, timefold

I make the constraint provider implementation class as component Spring and i inject it in the controller also i make a configuration bean implementation of ConstraintFactory and i inject it also in my controlleur.In the web service i fetch all constraints using constraintProvider and constraintFactory , i filter this constraints with the data body from the web service an i set constraint in the constraintProvider implementation class but it still use all constraints due to the defineConstraints method which i think execuded once in the execution of project. how i do dynamic constraints with Spring boot and Timefold also i want an exemple of code how i do that i read some stack-overflow's questions:

[Optaplanner : Add / remove constraints dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59751860/optaplanner-add-remove-constraints-dynamically)

[How to choose dynamically which constraints should be applied on the optimization problem based on the frontend input in Timefold Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78089782/how-to-choose-dynamically-which-constraints-should-be-applied-on-the-optimizatio)

I want an example of code. How i make dynamic constraints?

example of my code :

@Component
public class PlanningConstraintsProvider implementsConstraintProvider {

```
@Override
public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return new Constraint[]{
            noMissingSkills(constraintFactory),
            employeeTaskOverlapConstraint(constraintFactory),
            locationConstraint(constraintFactory)
    };
}

private Constraint noMissingSkills(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.forEach(Task.class)
            .filter(task -> task.getMissingSkillCount() > 0)
            .penalize(HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_HARD, Task::getMissingSkillCount)
            .asConstraint("NO_MISSING_SKILL");
}

private Constraint locationConstraint(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.forEach(Task.class)
            .penalize(HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_HARD,
                    task -> calculateWeightLocation(task.getAssignedEmployee().getLocation(), task.getLocation()))
            .asConstraint("LOCATION");
}
```

}
i want to calculate dynamicaly the weight for each 3 method with penalizeConfigurable and the constraint configuration class how to do that and justifyWith what is her role and for my solution i set attribute in construtor with the ConstraintConfiguration object then i do the solve with solve manager but it doesn't work respond with the correct solution how i do? i based this to this stack overflow response : [How to choose dynamically which constraints should be applied on the optimization problem based on the frontend input in Timefold Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78089782/how-to-choose-dynamically-which-constraints-should-be-applied-on-the-optimizatio/78123873#78123873)

my goal is to give the constraints that i want to take in consideration in solving from my API

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to choose dynamically which constraints should be applied on the optimization problem based on the frontend input in Timefold Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78089782/how-to-choose-dynamically-which-constraints-should-be-applied-on-the-optimizatio)

Comment: non i want plus explanation and example of code

Comment: @LukášPetrovický my goal is to give the constraints ,that i want to take in consideration in solving ,from my API  web service for exemple only noMissingSkills how i do that

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at @ConstraintConfiguration and @ConstraintWeight.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the answer correctly ([How to choose dynamically which constraints should be applied on the optimization problem based on the frontend input in Timefold Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78089782/how-to-choose-dynamically-which-constraints-should-be-applied-on-the-optimizatio)), in the ConstraintProvider you write all the constraints and in the ConstraintConfiguration you can do something like this:

1. Set all the constraints from ConstraintConfiguration to have a ZERO weight
2. In the initialization phase of the ConstraintConfiguration (in the constructor or @PostConstruct) you can take all the constraints from the database (which will be a list of String)
3. For every constraint from the list, check if the constraint can be found also in the ConstraintProvider. If the constraint can be found there, put some weight to be taken into account by the solver.

Please correct me if I am wrong. I hope this answer helps you.

You can find more information here: https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/constraints-and-score/constraint-configuration#constraintWeight

**Updated answer:**

I provided a solution here: [How to choose dynamically which constraints should be applied on the optimization problem based on the frontend input in Timefold Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78089782/how-to-choose-dynamically-which-constraints-should-be-applied-on-the-optimizatio/78123873#78123873)

Comment: i want in the rest API specify constraint's name then finding constraint by name i set these constraints to the provider and the solve will be done with these constraints. I don't understand  how to use ConstraintConfiguration and ConstraintWeight can you make an example of code with spring boot  of sending constraints dynamically from the web service

Comment: I posted an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78089782/how-to-choose-dynamically-which-constraints-should-be-applied-on-the-optimizatio/78123873#78123873. Check it out and let me know if the solution worked for you.

Comment: suppose i have method of constraint i have to do that .penalize(HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_HARD,
                        Task::getMissingSkillCount) how i trait that withdynamic constraints

Comment: i change rewardConfigurable that include ToIntFunction weight and if i want to panalise dynamicaly with weight ,i change in the switch case in the constractor of  ConstraintConfiguration class or in the ToIntFunction of rewardConfigurable and penalizeConfigurable?

Comment: it doesn't work correctly for me the web service don't response with the correct response , i make all the change like you said i don't know what is the problem also the problem in the two previous comment and think you

Comment: I assume that you added the @ConstraintWeight("value") annotation at every constraint in the ConstraintConfiguration Bean. Next, in the constraints method (within ConstraintProvider class) you have to add at the end of the constraint "asConstraint("value")" : .penalizeConfigurable().asConstraint("value"); 
In this way, the Solver will search by name/value in the ConstraintConfiguration the score configuration that you made to the specific constraint. I hope this makes sense for you. If not, mention what did you code your logic behind dynamic constraints to be able to debug.

Comment: If you want to penalize dynamically with weight, you should change in the Constructor of the ConstraintConfiguration class. The logic is the following: first, you set every constraint's weight to be zero and then, in the Constructor, you add a weight depending on what constraints you have (in your database, for example). In the Solver, it will take into account your latest configuration with the newly set weights (from the Constructor)

Comment: i update this question with some code and some and i explain what i mean