# How to write unit tests for Constraints where it is applied penalizeConfigurable() method in Timefold?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, optaplanner, timefold

Starting from the github project provided by Timefold (https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-quickstarts/tree/stable/technology/java-spring-boot) and extend it by using ConstraintConfiguration and ConstraintWeight to apply some dynamic constraints ([How to choose dynamically which constraints should be applied on the optimization problem based on the frontend input in Timefold Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78089782/how-to-choose-dynamically-which-constraints-should-be-applied-on-the-optimizatio)) I want to write some unit tests. How can I simulate the **ConstraintConfiguration** for the unit tests?

For the following test:

```
@Test
    void roomConflict() {
        Lesson firstLesson = new Lesson(1, "Subject1", new Teacher(1L, "Teacher1", null), new StudentGroup(1L,"Group1", 30), TIMESLOT1, ROOM1);
        Lesson conflictingLesson = new Lesson(2, "Subject2", new Teacher(2L, "Teacher2", null), new StudentGroup(2L,"Group2", 30), TIMESLOT1, ROOM1);
        Lesson nonConflictingLesson = new Lesson(3, "Subject3", new Teacher(3L, "Teacher3", null), new StudentGroup(3L,"Group3", 30), TIMESLOT2, ROOM1);
        constraintVerifier.verifyThat(TimetableConstraintProvider::roomConflict)
                .given(firstLesson, conflictingLesson, nonConflictingLesson)
                .penalizesBy(0, "roomConflict");
    }
```

I wanted to check the output, but I receive **a soft constraint justification instead of a hard one**:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: roomConflict
        Constraint: com.timetablealgo.testingtimetablealgo.solver/roomConflict
  Expected penalty: 0 (class java.lang.Integer)
    Actual penalty: 1 (class java.lang.Integer)

  Explanation of score (0hard/1soft):
    Constraint matches:
        1soft: constraint (roomConflict) has 1 matches:
            1soft: justified with (RoomConflictJustification[room=Room(id=1, name=Room1, capacity=0, type=null, building=null, dotari=null), lesson1=Lesson(id=1, subject=Subject1, teacher=Teacher(id=1, name=Teacher1, preferredTimeslot=null), studentGroup=StudentGroup(id=1, year=null, name=Group1, group=null, semiGroup=null, numberOfStudents=30), type=null, year=null, timeslot=Timeslot(id=1, dayOfWeek=MONDAY, startTime=12:00, endTime=14:00), room=Room(id=1, name=Room1, capacity=0, type=null, building=null, dotari=null)), lesson2=Lesson(id=2, subject=Subject2, teacher=Teacher(id=2, name=Teacher2, preferredTimeslot=null), studentGroup=StudentGroup(id=2, year=null, name=Group2, group=null, semiGroup=null, numberOfStudents=30), type=null, year=null, timeslot=Timeslot(id=1, dayOfWeek=MONDAY, startTime=12:00, endTime=14:00), room=Room(id=1, name=Room1, capacity=0, type=null, building=null, dotari=null)), description=Room 'Room(id=1, name=Room1, capacity=0, type=null, building=null, dotari=null)' is used for lesson 'Subject1' for student group 'StudentGroup(id=1, year=null, name=Group1, group=null, semiGroup=null, numberOfStudents=30)' and lesson 'Subject2' for student group 'StudentGroup(id=2, year=null, name=Group2, group=null, semiGroup=null, numberOfStudents=30)' at 'MONDAY 12:00'])
    Indictments:
        1soft: indicted with (Lesson(id=1, subject=Subject1, teacher=Teacher(id=1, name=Teacher1, preferredTimeslot=null), studentGroup=StudentGroup(id=1, year=null, name=Group1, group=null, semiGroup=null, numberOfStudents=30), type=null, year=null, timeslot=Timeslot(id=1, dayOfWeek=MONDAY, startTime=12:00, endTime=14:00), room=Room(id=1, name=Room1, capacity=0, type=null, building=null, dotari=null))) has 1 matches:
            1soft: constraint (roomConflict)
        1soft: indicted with (Lesson(id=2, subject=Subject2, teacher=Teacher(id=2, name=Teacher2, preferredTimeslot=null), studentGroup=StudentGroup(id=2, year=null, name=Group2, group=null, semiGroup=null, numberOfStudents=30), type=null, year=null, timeslot=Timeslot(id=1, dayOfWeek=MONDAY, startTime=12:00, endTime=14:00), room=Room(id=1, name=Room1, capacity=0, type=null, building=null, dotari=null))) has 1 matches:
            1soft: constraint (roomConflict)


    at ai.timefold.solver.test.impl.score.stream.DefaultSingleConstraintAssertion.assertImpact(DefaultSingleConstraintAssertion.java:135)
    at ai.timefold.solver.test.impl.score.stream.DefaultSingleConstraintAssertion.penalizesBy(DefaultSingleConstraintAssertion.java:48)
    at com.timetablealgo.testingtimetablealgo.solver.TimetableConstraintProviderTest.roomConflict(TimetableConstraintProviderTest.java:31)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
```

How can I solve this issue?

PS: I added some fields to the classes but they don't change the basic functionality provided by the Github project in any way.

Comment: I think this is an API gap in ConstraintVerifier; I created https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/issues/715 to track it.