Add constraints dynamically
I have saved a Java stream constraint as a varchar in database.
After fetching the record from the database, I converted it from a String to a Constraint object.
How can the schedule take into account this new Constraint into the existing constraints managed by the EmployeeRosteringConstraintProvider?

The simple answer is that it can not. Arguably, storing Java code in a database to have it later parsed and inserted into an executable is a practice that opens up all kinds of security issues, not to mention its compute inefficiency. If you explain the use case you are trying to solve, as opposed to going for a particular solution, maybe we'll come up with a better approach.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

For adding constraints dinamically, I proposed a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78089782/how-to-choose-dynamically-which-constraints-should-be-applied-on-the-optimizatio. Check it out and let me know if it helped you.

There are 2 techniques:
Use @ConstraintConfiguration and @ConstraintWeight.
If a ConstraintWeight for a constraint is ZERO, then there is no performance impact for that constraint.
Design your constraints to be more abstract. For example, for a day off request, use time span (between two datetimes) instead of date. That supports afternoon off requests too.
